# Can a const and var can have same name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I come across a code something like this:

```
const foo = 1
var foo = foo
foo = 2
```

What will be the value of of `foo`. Will it change, ignore or throw an error? For me in Node terminal it is ignoring the second line namely `var foo`.

Comment: No - they need unique names.

Comment: How Javascript differentiate variables other than closure and block scopes.

Comment: I don't think any language allows that. A const is technically just a variable which throws an error when modified.

Comment: I dont understand how you even **dare** ask those kind of question... Haven't you tried? It took me less than 10 seconds!

Answer (score 2):

You will get a syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared